# I can't use the iPhoto library as desktop backgrounds on Mavericks

Tags: macos, photos.app

Since updating to Mavericks, I can no longer select my iPhoto library (9.4.3) as source for the desktop background. In the left hand list, the iPhoto entry is present, but no folders and if I select the "root" iPhoto entry, only the default wallpaper will show.

I have rebooted several times without solving the problem.
The screensaver will find the library just fine.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do?

Edit:
I added a screenshot of how it looks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I had the problem also on Lion and Mountain Lion. If your library is large you have to wait a long time with the preferences open until you will see the albums

Comment: @Matteo I've waited for days...

Comment: With the preferences pane open? In my case it takes almost 10 minutes on MacBook Pro Retina (I opened a bug report by Apple but no reaction)

Comment: Yes, with the preferences pane open.

Comment: I have the latest version of iPhoto but I have this problem. I think the answers above indicating that it takes awhile to load large libraries is the problem. Often what will happen is I will open the Wallpaper pane and initially I won't see my iPhoto library in the list. However it seems to just show up suddenly upon rechecking. Right now however I am currently dealing with an issue where I had it set up so that an event in iPhoto was my background but then it suddenly reverted to the stock pics. This issue with iPhoto events and background is kind of annoying and I hope Apple fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using iPhoto's **Photo Library First Aid** and repairing the permissions of the iPhoto library.

To activate the **Photo Library First Aid**

Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd>+ <kbd>Command</kbd>  while starting iPhoto.

A Window with several options will appear.

To repair the permissions check **Repair Permissions** and click the **Repair** button

[image]

If that does not solve the problem, again activate **Photo Library First Aid** and try the next repair option, "Rebuild Thumbnails." Continue through repair options until problem is solved. (In my case, "repair permissions" was not sufficient, but "rebuild thumbnails" solved the problem, so that "Photo Library" appeared in selection list for screen saver.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this problem. iPhoto 9.5

Either you are expecting them to be right next to the Albums and events. When the actually are further down. As shown with my Folder named 'test2'

[image]

Or you could try and upgrade to 9.5 and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: I don't see anything under the iPhoto item, see the screenshot I added to the question...  Since I don't seem to be able to update to 9.5 without buying it again, I was hoping to solve it with 9.4.

Comment: Really. I did not have to re purchase?

Comment: Strange, I wonder why...